# How can I make a LibreOffice instance save a file, without using the GUI?

Tags: linux, remote-access, libreoffice, libreoffice-writer, autosave

I've gone abroad, leaving LibreOffice Writer open with some file I edited. Unfortunately - I forgot to press Save! Now, I have SSH access to that machine, but - how can I make LibreOffice save the file without me using the GUI? Can I signal it somehow?

I'm using Debian GNU/Linux Stretch.

Comment: have a look at this question: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/55310/how-to-attach-to-remote-machines-local-display-session-over-ssh    - You might be able to get a remote graphical view of the existing desktop session using vnc and x server

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I did not test your setup, but this worked for me from a terminal:

```bsh
xdotool search --name Untitled key ctrl+s
xdotool search --name Untitled key ctrl+q
```

"Untitled 1" was the name of the document in my test.  <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>s</kbd> saves, and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>q</kbd> quits.

See https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/87831/how-to-send-keystrokes-f5-from-terminal-to-a-process.

Alternatively, if you force kill the process, next time it should open in recover mode.  Probably it will be able to recover most or all of the changes.

Comment: Does this rely on the application and document being what is in focus on that machine?

Comment: No, LibreOffice was never in the foreground during my test.  A different window was active instead.

Comment: So, I tried this, and while I did manage to find the window with xdotool search --name "the_filename.odt" and get a number - appending "key ctrl+s" did not do anything.